# Click on waypoint of bingmap

Tags: javascript, routes, bing-maps, directions

I have a map with bingmap and I implemented waypoints. I would like when I click in a waypoint it displays an info window.

```
if (!$scope.directionsManager) { _createDirectionsManager(); }
    if($scope.directionsManager.getAllWaypoints().length < 2)
    {
      $scope.directionsManager.resetDirections();
      $scope.waypoints.forEach(function (waypoint) {
        var order_waypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(waypoint.lat, waypoint.lng) });
        console.log("order_waypoint", order_waypoint)
        $scope.directionsManager.addWaypoint(order_waypoint);
      })
    }
    var renderOption = {
        itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsItinerary'),

        waypointPushpinOptions:{
            // icon: "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/freeciv/images/1/1c/Crystal_128_penguin.png/revision/latest?cb=20071106133132&path-prefix=es",
            // hoverIcon: "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/freeciv/images/1/1c/Crystal_128_penguin.png/revision/latest?cb=20071106133132&path-prefix=es",
            // height: 10,
            // width: 10,
            draggable: false,
            textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-1, 3)
        }
    }
    $scope.directionsManager.setRenderOptions(renderOption);
    $scope.directionsManager.calculateDirections();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Bing maps API, but [the docs on the Waypoint class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312838.aspx) make it look like you might need [a custom pushpin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312830.aspx) in order to intercept [its click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615.aspx#sectionSection2).

```
var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(waypoint.lat, waypoint.lng);
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', function() {
    // Implementation can go here
});

var order_waypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(
    {location: location, pushpin: pushpin});
$scope.directionsManager.addWaypoint(order_waypoint);
```

It is possible you can get a reference to the default `pushpin` on `order_waypoint` without creating your own custom one, and use `addHandler` to bind the click event to it. I don't have running code to test that on, and [I don't see a way to get a reference to the default pushpin, only the custom one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312838.aspx). You could try it anyway (`order_waypoint.getPushpin()`) and see if it works.